# How to apply different css classes to asp:panels in different ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, listview, itemdatabound

I have a listview and in It's ItemTemplate, a asp:panel which includes some controls.
I need to apply three different css class to the asp:panel, depending on value of one of the controls in my asp:panel.

here's my code:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        HiddenField type = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("valueOfAd_type");
        HiddenField paid = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("valueOfPayment");
        Panel ThePanel = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("Panel1");
        if ( paid.Value == "2")
        {
            if (type.Value == "1")   //First condition
            {
                ThePanel.Attributes.Add("class", "whiteBackground");
            }
            else if (type.Value == "2")  //Second condition
            {
                ThePanel.Attributes.Add("class", "redBackground"); 
            }
        }
        else  //third condition
        {
            ThePanel.Attributes.Add("class", "blueBackground");
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, no matter which condition occurs, always the last css class will be apply to all of my asp:panels.
now my question is how to apply different css classes to asp:panels in different ItemTemplate?

Comment: You should add the alternating item for your `ItemTemplate`.  Why don't you try this comparison: `String.Compare(type.Value, "2") == 0)`?  Also the panel should have `CssClass` attribute, for you to add to the Control.

Answer (score 0):

To better assist you, we would need the front-end syntax.  That way we can see all of your Panel(s) that exist within the `ItemTemplate`.  Based on your code it appears to be a single Panel.

Otherwise, I did notice the following:

- You don't account for alternating item(s).
- The comparison would be better, with `String.Compare(...);`.
- Only one Panel is being called, which would be why only that one Panel color changes.

Also, you can simplify the code:

```
control.CssClass = "style";
```

You also stated that it always displays a blue background, I would verify that a value actually enters your initial `if` statement.